# Nest a dynamic AJAX function in a javascript function - And keep it updating

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have AJAX code

```
<!-- Body Code -->
Listeners: <span id="cc_stream_info_listeners"></span>

<!-- Footer Code -->   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/system/streaminfo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/js.php/radio/streaminfo/rnd0"></script>
```

Which returns dynamic listener count for an online radio stream. This code works fine, but the js files are on a remote host. So I don't really know how they work.

I want the page title of one of my pages to dynamically include the listener count. Much like a twitter page counts the new tweets that are available in your feed.

E.g. `(5) My Dashboard | My Site Name` Where the number is the dynamic listener count from the AJAX function.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<!-- START: PAGE TITLE LISTENER CONTENT -->
<script>
function updatetitle() {
  var txt1 = "(";
  var txt2 = "5";
  var txt3 = ") My Dashboard | My Site Name";
  var n = txt1.concat(txt2,txt3);
  document.title = n;
}
</script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  updatetitle();
};
</script>
```

Simply replacing the text "5" with `<span id="cc_stream_info_listeners">` doesn't work. But at least I know I have the page update component correct. As it's working as expected with the plain text.

How can I merge these two functions - So that listener count is updated dynamically?

Comment: Does the ajax call fire immediately when the .js file is loaded? Or can you call the ajax function at your leisure?

Comment: Good question. I'm not 100% sure. Currently (in the body), when the page loads the listener count is immediately displayed. Then it updates every 120 seconds or so. Interestingly enough, if you leave the page open long enough, eventually it stops updating. So I think there could be a time out. But I don't want to confuse things. Sorry I can't tell you more about the ajax. But I don't directly have control on when to call/update the listener count.

Comment: Assuming it is not minified / obfuscated, can you provide the actual URL to the remote javascript you're using (the one that's doing the ajax call)? I suppose you can technically run your updating code every 120 seconds (or something shorter) as well, and hope it coincides with this other ajax, but there may be a better way if we can see the that code.

Comment: Actually, I followed the link and can read the ajax. Here it is...

`function refresh_cc_stream_info(){var ccsib=document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];var ccsis=document.createElement('script');ccsis.type='text/javascript';ccsis.src=window.ccsiu;ccsib.appendChild(ccsis)}
function cc_streaminfo_get_callback(ccsiv){for(n in ccsiv)if(ccsie=document.getElementById('cc_stream_info_'+n))ccsie.innerHTML=ccsiv[n];window.ccsiu=ccsiv.url;if(window.ccsic++
<60)setTimeout('refresh_cc_stream_info()',60000);}
window.ccsic=0;`

That's the first link in my footer.

Comment: Hmm, that's only part of it, the actual ajax must be some where else. Is the value of `window.ccsic` what you want? IF so, perhaps a simple solution is to make your own function that loops periodically using setTimeout that simply changes the page title to what you want; doesn't matter if the value was changed, just replace the title as you were doing using the `window.ccsis` value. Barring that, is it possible to ditch their javascript functions and simply make your own ajax call using the same URL or something like that? Or, does this thing, whatever you're using, have any documentation?

Comment: Side note: See that `if(window.ccsic++ < 60)` line, that's the reason you've observed it stops updating after a while. If that condition evaluates to true, it'll refresh again, otherwise it stops.

Comment: I'm happy with a custom loop. Though I had hoped I could just wrap the output of the ajax, convert to int and it would work though. Might have been too ambitious. I'll PM you the links. You might be able to see something I can't. Also... I added `window.ccsic` and it populated with `1`. Which is interesting. Where's this chat button?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37424/discussion-between-teeg-and-square-eyes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MutationObserver to check when the element `#cc_stream_info_listeners` was modified: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

You pick a node to observe. For your project you should observe `cc_stream_info_listeners`. Then, whenever the dom changes, a callback will be fired. This reduces the strain on the browser that a setInterval would induce, since it's only called when the event actually happens.

Modified from the documentation: http://jsfiddle.net/E5Rrc/

```
    // select the target node
    var title_tag = document.querySelector('title');
    var cc_stream_info_listeners = document.querySelector('#cc_stream_info_listeners');

    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
          title_tag.innerHTML = '('+cc_stream_info_listeners.innerHTML+') My Dashboard | My Site Name';
      });    
    });

    // configuration of the observer:
    var config = { childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(cc_stream_info_listeners, config);

    // this is just for testing, to show that it works.
    setInterval(function() {
        cc_stream_info_listeners.innerHTML++;
    }, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great idea. I call the .js file I have created with the code you suggested. `#title_tag: <span id="title_tag"></span>
` propagates blank unfortunately. Could the existing AJAX be interfering?

Comment: `#title_tag` was just for the example. For your project, you want to modify the `title` tag, as in the browser's text in the tab, right?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but you have lost me:) Where do I find my title tag? And what parts of your code do I need to update?

Comment: The title tag is in `<head><title></title></head>`. The only line that needs to change is `var title_tag = document.querySelector('title');` depending on what you want to update.

Comment: I can't read between the lines. Thanks for sticking with me though. I have the .js file in place, and call it from my page body. What code do I need to implement to insert the captured listener count? FYI I use Wordpress if that helps. Do I use the `window.onload` from my original post?

Comment: Sorry I'm on the train now. I'll be back in a few hours.

Comment: Does this solution require me to add a div around the title tag to select it? I can't figure out how to select it using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector). I want to update the contents of the title. But nothing I put in the js document.querySelector has any impact on my page. I can confirm the js is firing off though.

Comment: Do I also need to change `document.querySelector('#cc_stream_info_listeners');`?

Comment: The .js file will update an element named `cc_stream_info_listeners`, so your observer will need to observe `#cc_stream_info_listeners`. Whenever `cc_stream_info_listeners` changes, you want the modification to carry over to `title`. I've made the script as easy as possible. You don't need to modify any of it. Just make sure you have an element somewhere on your page with `id="cc_stream_info_listeners"` and put this script after it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37446/discussion-between-square-eyes-and-joe-frambach)

Comment: "and put this script after it." - OK it works. Thanks for hanging in there. I had the script above `<span id="cc_stream_info_server"></span>`. I simply had to include the `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myproject/listeners_title_update.js"></script>` after. Also in my confusion I used your jsfiddle code without fully understanding it. I made myself follow the logic and realised why the code submitted above was slightly different.